# Git log with color and name-rev

Tags: git, sh

Is it possible to get a log with colored graph output and named revisions like `git log --graph | git name-rev --stdin | less` but with color output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add to your first command `--color=always`:

```
git log --graph --color=always | git name-rev --stdin | less
```

You don't even need to use `less -R`, as suggested in "[Get colors in '`less'`' command](https://superuser.com/a/275869/141)".

[image: example git log with colors]

Comment: I can't beleive the answer is so easy. Thank you very much!